# Where to place view files for Laravel Excel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I have code to export data to blade template:

```
namespace App\Exports;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;

class InvoicesExport implements FromView
{
    public function view(): View
    {
        return view('exports.invoices', [
            'invoices' => Invoice::all()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Where I should place view file `exports.invoices`?

I tried to place it in path: `App\Exports` like:

```
/App/Exports/exports/invoices.blade.php
```

But Excel can not find this path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to place all your views in `app/resources/views` directory. From there, you can create numerous directories for your needs.

Also, you are using a `view()` global helper, which by default tries to find views in the directory I mentioned above. This is also explained in Laravel official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views).

Comment: What is path? App\Export\Invoices.blade.php?

Comment: `resources/views/exports/invoices.blade.php` it has to be this  since the `view()` function will look in for the files in the views folder, `exports.invoices` means that its in a folder called exports while the file is `invoices.blade.php`

Comment: It can not find this path

Comment: What do you mean you can't find this path? There is no app/resources/views directory in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Make a Folder resources/views/exports. You have placed the blade in the wrong directory